# Mailpoet Custom Forms and Custom Fields

Tags: forms, wordpress

I've created a custom mailpoet form and am trying to add subscribers through it. It works when I don't try to post custom form field data. Does anyone know how I can make it work with custom form fields? In the database it has cf_1, cf_2 etc and this is what I've tried amending the code here without much luck: https://support.mailpoet.com/knowledgebase/plugin-form-integrate/

```
$user_data = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'cf_1' => $phone,
    'cf_2' => $company_name,
    'cf_3' => $dob,
);
```

Any ideas? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I trawled through some of the plugin's code and figured out how to do it. So based on the example given by the plugin authors I've made this change:

```
//in this array firstname and lastname are optional
$user_data = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname
);

$custom_data = array(
    'cf_1' => $phone,
);

$data_subscriber = array(
  'user' => $user_data,
  'user_field' => $custom_data,
  'user_list' => array('list_ids' => array(3))
);

$helper_user = WYSIJA::get('user','helper');
$helper_user->addSubscriber($data_subscriber);
```

So pretty much in the data_subscriber multidimensional array you need to add an another field for "user_field" and that should be an array, see the $custom_data array I created.

Tested and works, hope that helps someone else!